# AWS transcribe Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain

Tags: amazon-transcribe, aws-credentials

I am running a java program that uses AWS TranscribeStreaming. I have created(from AWS console) and downloaded AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY then set the environment variables.
When I run the program I am getting error message:

> Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain.

I don't why but this error was also occurring while using Google SDK for speech recognition.

here is the code I am trying to run.

```
public class TranscribeStreamingDemoApp {

    private static final Region REGION = Region.US_WEST_2;
    private static TranscribeStreamingAsyncClient client;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws URISyntaxException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException, LineUnavailableException {
      
        client = TranscribeStreamingAsyncClient.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(getCredentials())
                .region(REGION)
                .build();

        CompletableFuture<Void> result = client.startStreamTranscription(getRequest(16_000),
                new AudioStreamPublisher(getStreamFromMic()),
                getResponseHandler());

        result.get();
        client.close();
    }

    private static InputStream getStreamFromMic() throws LineUnavailableException {

        // Signed PCM AudioFormat with 16kHz, 16 bit sample size, mono
        int sampleRate = 16000;
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            System.out.println("Line not supported");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open(format);
        line.start();

        InputStream audioStream = new AudioInputStream(line);
        return audioStream;
    }

    private static AwsCredentialsProvider getCredentials() {
        return DefaultCredentialsProvider.create();
    }

    private static StartStreamTranscriptionRequest getRequest(Integer mediaSampleRateHertz) {
        return StartStreamTranscriptionRequest.builder()
                .languageCode(LanguageCode.FR_FR.toString())
                .mediaEncoding(MediaEncoding.PCM)
                .mediaSampleRateHertz(mediaSampleRateHertz)
                .build();
    }

    private static StartStreamTranscriptionResponseHandler getResponseHandler() {
        return StartStreamTranscriptionResponseHandler.builder()
                .onResponse(r -> {
                    System.out.println("Received Initial response");
                })
                .onError(e -> {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                    System.out.println("Error Occurred: " + sw.toString());
                })
                .onComplete(() -> {
                    System.out.println("=== All records stream successfully ===");
                })
                .subscriber(event -> {
                    List<software.amazon.awssdk.services.transcribestreaming.model.Result> results = ((TranscriptEvent) event).transcript().results();
                    if (results.size() > 0) {
                        if (!results.get(0).alternatives().get(0).transcript().isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println(results.get(0).alternatives().get(0).transcript());
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    private InputStream getStreamFromFile(String audioFileName) {
        try {
            File inputFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(audioFileName).getFile());
            InputStream audioStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            return audioStream;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static class AudioStreamPublisher implements Publisher<AudioStream> {

        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private static Subscription currentSubscription;

        private AudioStreamPublisher(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super AudioStream> s) {

            if (this.currentSubscription == null) {
                this.currentSubscription = new SubscriptionImpl(s, inputStream);
            } else {
                this.currentSubscription.cancel();
                this.currentSubscription = new SubscriptionImpl(s, inputStream);
            }
            s.onSubscribe(currentSubscription);
        }
    }

    public static class SubscriptionImpl implements Subscription {

        private static final int CHUNK_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 1024 * 1;
        private final Subscriber<? super AudioStream> subscriber;
        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        private AtomicLong demand = new AtomicLong(0);

        SubscriptionImpl(Subscriber<? super AudioStream> s, InputStream inputStream) {
            this.subscriber = s;
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        public void request(long n) {
            if (n <= 0) {
                subscriber.onError(new IllegalArgumentException("Demand must be positive"));
            }

            demand.getAndAdd(n);

            executor.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    do {
                        ByteBuffer audioBuffer = getNextEvent();
                        if (audioBuffer.remaining() > 0) {
                            AudioEvent audioEvent = audioEventFromBuffer(audioBuffer);
                            subscriber.onNext(audioEvent);
                        } else {
                            subscriber.onComplete();
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (demand.decrementAndGet() > 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel() {
            executor.shutdown();
        }

        private ByteBuffer getNextEvent() {
            ByteBuffer audioBuffer = null;
            byte[] audioBytes = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE_IN_BYTES];

            int len = 0;
            try {
                len = inputStream.read(audioBytes);

                if (len <= 0) {
                    audioBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(0);
                } else {
                    audioBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(audioBytes, 0, len);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }

            return audioBuffer;
        }

        private AudioEvent audioEventFromBuffer(ByteBuffer bb) {
            return AudioEvent.builder()
                    .audioChunk(SdkBytes.fromByteBuffer(bb))
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved the problem, the documentation specifies that:
AWS credentials provider chain that looks for credentials in this order:
1.Java System Properties - aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretAccessKey
2.Environment Variables - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
3.Credential profiles file at the default location (~/.aws/credentials) shared by all AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI

Since setting up through environment variables didn't work, I opted to set credentials with Java system properties and it works!
Doc ref: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/DefaultCredentialsProvider.html

```
 System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", "**************");
    System.setProperty("aws.secretAccessKey", "**************");
```